# Update duplicate records on referencing table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

Table A:

```
ID    NAME
1     First
2     Second
3     Second
4     Third
5     First
```

Table B (referencing Table A records):

```
A_ID    REC
1       10
2       10
3       20
4       20
5       20
3       30
```

Table A has 2 duplicate records which i can easily delete, but i need to update Table B with lesser ids of duplicate records. I want to end up with:

```
A_ID    REC
1       10
2       10
2       20
4       20
1       20
2       30
```

I have solved this for MySQL but got stuck on Oracle since Oracle does not support joins in the UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a query.  First, to get the new id:

```
select a1.id, min(a2.id) as min_id
from a a1 left join
     a a2
     on a1.name = a2.name
group by a1.id;
```

Then, as a query:

```
select b.*, a.min_id
from b join
     (select a1.id, min(a2.id) as min_id
      from a a1 left join
           a a2
           on a1.name = a2.name
      group by a1.id
     ) a
     on b.a_id = a.id;
```

If you really need an update, that is a bit tricky:

```
update b
    set b.a_id = (select min(a2.id) as min_id
                  from a a1 left join
                       a a2
                       on a1.name = a2.name
                  where a1.id = b.a_id
                 )
    where b.id <> (select min(a2.id) as min_id
                   from a a1 left join
                        a a2
                        on a1.name = a2.name
                   where a1.id = b.a_id
                  )
```

Comment: Seems to be working for both mssql and oracle as a bonus! Thanks.